# Laravel jQuery - Check if row exists in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

In my application, I build a page where the user sees a progress bar which displays the progress of an action that is happening in the background. One part of this progress bar is the following: I have to check in jQuery if a certain row with a certain id exists in the database. If it does exist, The progress bar has to skip to 30%. If it does not exists then It has to do nothing.

I have a database table called `Droplets`, In there-there is a field called `Webshop_id`. If a `Droplet` exists in this table which has the `webshop_id` of the one that the user just created, The progress bar goes to 30%.

A small summary to clarify

- Check if a `droplet` with the `webshop_id` exists in the database using jQuery
- If it does exist, Make the progress bar a width of 30%;
- If it does NOT exists. Do nothing.

A simple if-statement in PHP of this issue would look something like this

```
if( Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $webshop->id)->exists())

    Make the progress bar 30% in width

else {

    Just do nothing

}
```

But this needs to be done in jQuery in order to make the progress bar a width of 30%. What is the best way to handle this issue?

The page where this needs to happen looks like this.

```
@extends('layouts.home') @section('content')
<div class="container" id="showEffect">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="card depth-5 p-4 mb-5">
    <div class="card-header p-4 bg-white">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 class="mb-4 text-green"><i class="fal fa-check-circle mr-3"></i> Payment succesfull!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p class="text-muted m-0">Thank you! Your payment has been recieved! The order is confirmed. A reciept is being send to <b>{{ $order->user->email }}</b></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h5>Summary</h5>
          <div class="card depth-2">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li class="text-muted">Payment ID:</li>
                    <li class="text-muted">Order date:</li>
                    <li class="text-muted">Payment method:</li>
                    <li class="text-muted">Total sum: </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>{{ $payment->id }}</li>
                    <li>{{ $order->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}</li>
                    <li>{{ $payment->method }}</li>
                    <li>€ {{ $order->price_sum }}</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer mt-3 bg-white">
      <h4>Your Webshop</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Your webshop is installing! We advise you not to click away if u want to prevent cancelling the installation</p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
          <h3>37%</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <div class="progress mb-3">
            <div id="progress-install" class="progress-bar andcode-progress progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
          <a href="" class="btn btn-orange disabled">See the result</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

{{ $webshop->id }}

<div class="andcode-clouds">

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var checkdb = function() {
  // Bestaat de droplet met de webshop id van de aangemaakte webshop in de database. Als deze wel bestaat, Spring naar 30%. Als hij niet bestaat. Dan niks
  var ele = document.getElementById('progress-install');
  ele.style.width = 30 + '%';
 };
 setInterval(checkdb(), 1000 * 60);
 })
 </script>
 @endsection
```

I can call `{{ $webshop->id }}` anytime in this blade file. This ID has to match to the "Webshop_ID" in the droplets table

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: ` Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $webshop->id`? where did you get the $webshop->id?

Comment: @JamesRaidy I gave it with the view from the controller. The `$webshop->id` needs to match with the webshop_id in the droplets table

Answer (score 0):

Make one controller function with your logic

```
function() {
    if( Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $webshop->id)->exists())

       $id_exists = 1;

    else {

        $id_exists = 0;

    }

    return response()->json(['id_exists' => $id_exists]);
}
```

Then in your blade file

In script make ajax call to above controller function and get value of id_exists now you can decide whether to show progressbar or not upon this result

Answer (score 0):

You can use do this from database and controller validation in such way

```
$table->string('abc')->unique();
```

This is your table column in migration file

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'abc'=>'table_name:unique',
]);
```

This is your controller code in which **abc** is your request key and in
**$table->string('abc')->unique();** which is your column name of table and table_name is your table name you must replace with your own table name.